# Data from tags not being passed correctly to the new Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this method which takes tag data and sends it to another Activity.
When I step through this method in the debugger, I can see that the values are the expected ones.

```
public void ShowView(TextView tv, ImageView iv) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySeekAgain.class);
    String text_tag = tv.getTag().toString();
    String image_tag = iv.getTag().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, text_tag);     //example: "Joe Brown"
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, image_tag);   //example: "profilePic1"
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

The expected values are fine:

- text_tag: "Joe Brown"
- image_tag: "profilePic1"

However, in the new Activity, the text_tag value becomes the image_tag value.

```
public class DisplaySeekAgain extends AppCompatActivity {

private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);  //example: "profilePic1"
    String image = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE);   //example: "profilePic1"
```

The expected values are wrong:

- message = "profilePic1"
- image = "profilePic1"

I'm not sure why the "message" string is not coming over correctly.
Is there something I'm doing in my code that could be causing it?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you actually showed `EXTRA_NAME` and `EXTRA_IMAGE`. but those seem to be the exact same.

Comment: you should have this two variables:  `public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "extra-name"` and `public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "extra-image"`. Check the value of these two Strings, the value must be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putExtra only allows you to pass one `String` at a time. You need to use `Bundle` to allow multiple `String`'s to be passed to your next Activity. Each time you call:

`intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, text_tag);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, image_tag);`

you are overwriting `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, text_tag);` with `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, image_tag);`.

The below code should fix this.

```
public void ShowView(TextView tv, ImageView iv) {
String text_tag = tv.getTag().toString();
String image_tag = iv.getTag().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySeekAgain.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString(EXTRA_NAME, text_tag);     //example: "Joe Brown"
extras.putString(EXTRA_IMAGE, image_tag);   //example: "profilePic1"
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);

}


public class DisplaySeekAgain extends AppCompatActivity {

private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

String message = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);  //example: "profilePic1"
String image = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE);   //example: "profilePic1"
```

Answer (score 1):

> The expected values are fine:
>
> - `text_tag = "Joe Brown"`
> - `image_tag = "profilePic1"`

As shown...

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, text_tag);     //example: "Joe Brown"
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, image_tag);   //example: "profilePic1"
```

However,

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);  //example: "profilePic1"
```

Then, `EXTRA_NAME.equals(EXTRA_IMAGE)`, and you are only putting one extra value, therefore overriding anything else previously set.